# How to modify a certain row of a matrix, which has to be called by paste()

Tags: r, matrix, paste, assign

In a first large Loop I generated 1,000,000 matrices XY_1_1, ..., XY_1000_1000:

```
for (i in 1:1000){
   for (j in 1:1000){
        assign(paste0("XY",i,j ,sep='_'), matrix(ncol=10, nrow=4))
   }
}
```

Now I want to assign different outcomes of a function (vector of length 10) to the rth row of the matrices, which should somehow like this:

```
for (r in 1:4){
  for (i in 1000){
    for (j in 1:1000){
       assign(paste0("XY",i,j ,sep='_')[r,], function(i,j,r))
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error `'incorrect number of dimensions'`.
Furthermore, I tried using the `get()`-Function:

```
for (r in 1:4){
  for (i in 1000){
    for (j in 1:1000){
       get(paste0("XY",i,j ,sep='_'))[r,] <-  function(i,j,r)
    }
  }
}
```

which brought the error `'target of assignment expands to non-language object'`. Does anyone know a proper solution? Let me know in case you need further information.

Comment: By rth row, are you intending to change the same row in every matrix?

Comment: Yes, this is right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider saving all objects into a list using `lapply` especially since they are the same structure. With this approach, you avoid millions of matrices flooding your global environment becoming a management headache! Plus, you can easily run the same operations like the rth row across all matrix elements. Additionally, you avoid nested `for` loops or using `assign` and `get` and `eval(parse(paste...)))`. And then you still can get those million objects from list, using `list2env`:

```
# LIST OF A MILLION MATRICES (SAME DIMS) 
matlist <- lapply(seq(1000000), function(i) matrix(ncol=10, nrow=4))

# NAMING LIST ITEMS
itemnames <- paste0("XY", c(outer(seq(1000), seq(1000), paste0)))
matlist <- setNames(matlist, itemnames)

# UPDATING MATRIX
matlist <- setNames(lapply(seq(length(matlist)), function(i){        
    mat <- matlist[[i]]
    for (r in seq(4)) {
        mat[r,] <- some_function(i,r)
    }  
    return(mat)
}), itemnames)

# OUTPUT INDIVIDUAL ELEMENTS TO SEPARATE GLOBAL OBJECTS
list2env(matlist, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Alternately, they could use a four-dimensional array or a matrix of matrices, like `m = matrix(list(), 2, 2); m[[1, 1]] <- matrix(1:20, 4)`

Comment: Indeed, @Frank! OP can even use an array: `a <- array(NA, dim=c(4,5,4))`.

Comment: I think they need 4 dimensions, i, j, r and column...?